# How to Integrate the AWS Appsync with Django Application Deployed in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

We've deployed our Backend Application built based on Django framework, and it has few graphql APIs

Can we integrate them to appsync? if yes what are the ways and if there are any cons by doing this?

I've seen AWS Docs related to implementing using Direct Resolvers, (no Django part) in [this blog](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-lambda-powertools-python/2.14.1/core/event_handler/appsync/#resolver-decorator), i can't find resources related to Django Based resolvers